# Can't call stored procedure in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I write a `stored procedure` in `PostgreSQL`. I try to use, this procedure in java, it throw '`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor " < unnamed portal 1  > " does not exist`' exception.

procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION subject_show(session_id CHARACTER VARYING,OUT result_cursor refcursor, OUT total_record INTEGER, OUT total_search_record INTEGER  ) AS $$
        BEGIN
            total_record:=23;
            total_search_record:=22;
            OPEN result_cursor FOR SELECT "ID","NAME"   FROM "SUBJECTS" ;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call procedure, in `java` :

```
...

callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ call subject_show(?,?,?,?) }");
callableStatement.setString(1, sessionID);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.REF);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(callableStatement.getObject(3));
System.out.println(callableStatement.getObject(4));
rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that, 
I can only do this if you have autocommit turned off.  Cursors are 
only valid within a transaction , thus as soon as the driver commits the 
cursor is no longer valid.  Thus the error I am receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my code by adding @Transactional to the function